# overflow: hidden messing up nav-tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 nav-tabs bar, which I divided into "main tabs" and "sub tabs" that slide out of the main tabs with jquery's animate(). See code below:

CSS:

```
.nav-tabs .nav-item.main-item{
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: white;
}
.nav-tabs .nav-item.sub-item {
    background: rgba(240,240,240,1);
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item main-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#main1"><b>Main 1</b></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item main-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#main2"><b>Main 2</b></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item sub-item" main="#main1"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#sub1">Sub 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item sub-item" main="#main1"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#sub2">Sub 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item sub-item" main="#main1"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#sub3">Sub 3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item sub-item" main="#main1"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#sub4">Sub 4</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item sub-item" main="#main1"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#sub5">Sub 5</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item main-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Main 3"><b>Plan</b></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item main-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Main 4"><b>Simulate</b></a></li>
</ul>
```

JS: (jQuery)

```
$(".nav-tabs .nav-item.main-item").click(function (){
    var hr = $(this).find(".nav-link").attr("href");
    $(".nav-tabs .nav-item.sub-item:not([main="+hr+"])").stop().animate({width: 'hide'});
    $(".nav-tabs .nav-item.sub-item[main="+hr+"]").stop().animate({width: 'show'});
});
```

While it does technically work, during the animation, the bar gets messed up, by what I've already determined to be the "overflow: hidden" that gets set by jQuery for the animation. See images below:

Expanded:
[Nav-tabs sub items fully expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTNxB.png)

During Animation:
[Nav-tabs sub items during animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBk3S.png)

So basically it seems like overflow: hidden adds some kind of hidden margin that pushes the other elements (the main tabs) down. Other questions about overflow: hidden all were solved by removing margins and setting elements to display: inline-block; But in my case there are already no margins and everything already has inline-block.
I have tried nesting the sub-part in an other div. I have also tried replacing all ul and li elements with divs in the whole nav and playing around with alot of css properties and so on... but everything ends up with the same result.

I have spent days now trying to solve this without result so I hope somebody can help me out.

EDIT:
People suggested to add overflow:hidden in css to the sub-tabs, yet it causes the expanded state to be messed up as well. Sample:
[Messed up expanded state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHvq9.png)

Comment: Have you tried changing the animation to something else?

Comment: @KitangaNday I just tried changing it to a slideUp/slideDown and the result is once again the same thing. It's definitely a problem that the "overflow: hidden" causes, which is applied doing any animation.

Comment: Can you inspect the animation in the devtools to see what might be causing that issue. https://css-tricks.com/inspecting-animations-in-devtools/

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

New JS -

```
$(function() {
    function hidemenus() {
    var hr = $("ul.nav-tabs>li.main-item > a.active").attr("href");
    hr = hr.replace(/#/, "");
    $(".nav-tabs .nav-item.sub-item[main=" + hr + "]").stop().animate({
       width: 'show'
    });
    $(".nav-tabs .nav-item.sub-item:not([main=" + hr + "])").stop().animate({
       width: 'hide'
    });

    }

    hidemenus();

    $(".nav-tabs > .nav-item.main-item > .nav-link").click(function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();
      $(".nav-tabs > .nav-item.main-item > .nav-link").removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      hidemenus();

    });

});
```

see latest [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/topwebsite4you/u7sr9h6j/95/)

Comment: While the jsFiddle did seem to work, in my real case, it only lead to the expanded state now being messed up as well. As soon as the overflow: hidden comes into play, it messes up. I can't really see the difference between the cases though.. so I don't understand.

Comment: I'm sorry, it could be just me, but I'm not seeing the relevance of your updated answer. As far as I can see, nothing about it is applicable to my case. Did you perhaps mean to add that to another question?

Comment: While I do appreciate the improvements to my JS, it doesn't solve the problem I'm experiencing with the layout getting displaced in my case, which is caused by the "overflow: hidden" (probably in combination with some other css, which I can't figure out)

Answer (score -1):

Please Try This

```
.nav-tabs .nav-item.sub-item {
    background: rgba(240,240,240,1);
    margin-left: -5px;
     overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned to AlexP, this only causes the expanded state to be messed up as well. Adding the overflow: hidden makes it messed up, wether it's in css or through the jQuery animate().